# Why is my hungarian algorithm application function not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function, hungarian-algorithm

I want to solve this combinatorial optimization task using Hungarian algorithm:

Different teams of the same company may have employees in different cities. If employees have the same position, we can swap them. And the goal is to distribute employees to teams in such a way as to maximize the number of teams that have employees which are together in the same city.
Data we have consists of 4 columns:  employee's id, employee's team, employee's position, employee's city. The goal is to redistribute employees across teams and get a table with 4 columns:  employee's id, employee's team, employee's position, employee's city

Example:
input:

```
    employee_id    team_id  position    city
             1       0.0    Manager     New York
             2       0.0    Manager     San Francisco
             3       1.0    Engineer    Boston
             4       1.0    Engineer    Boston
             5       2.0    Engineer    London
             6       2.0    Engineer    London
             7       2.0    Manager     New York
```

output:

```
    employee_id    team_id  position    city
             1       0.0    Manager     New York
             7       0.0    Manager     New York
             3       1.0    Engineer    Boston
             4       1.0    Engineer    Boston
             5       2.0    Engineer    London
             6       2.0    Engineer    London
             2       2.0    Manager     San Francisco
```

as you see employees with id 7 and 2 were swapped and now all employees of team 0.0 are in New York.

i wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def hungarian(cost_matrix):
    row_ind, col_ind = opt.linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
    return row_ind, col_ind

def redistribute_employees(employee_data, cost_matrix):
    n = len(employee_data)
    row_ind, col_ind = hungarian(cost_matrix)
    new_teams = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        new_teams[i] = col_ind[int(employee_data[i, 1])]
    return np.column_stack((employee_data[:, 0], new_teams, employee_data[:, 2], employee_data[:, 3]))

employee_data = np.array([[1, 0, 'Manager', 'New York'],
                          [2, 0, 'Manager', 'San Francisco'],
                          [3, 1, 'Engineer', 'Boston'],
                          [4, 1, 'Engineer', 'Boston'],
                          [5, 2, 'Engineer', 'London'],
                          [6, 2, 'Engineer', 'London'],
                          [7, 2, 'Manager', 'New York']])
city_map = {'New York': 0, 'San Francisco': 1, 'Boston': 2, 'London': 3}
n = len(employee_data)
cost_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if employee_data[i, 2] == employee_data[j, 2] and employee_data[i, 3] != employee_data[j, 3]:
            cost_matrix[i, j] = 1

redistributed_employees = redistribute_employees(employee_data, cost_matrix)
print(redistributed_employees)
```

The condition `employee_data[i, 2] == employee_data[j, 2] and employee_data[i, 3] != employee_data[j, 3]` checks if two employees have the same position `(employee_data[i, 2] == employee_data[j, 2])` but work in different cities `(employee_data[i, 3] != employee_data[j, 3])`. In other words, it checks if two employees can be swapped without affecting the position but making sure that they are not working in the same city.

print of cost_matrix is: `array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])`

But the output is:

```
[['1' '0.0' 'Manager' 'New York']
 ['2' '0.0' 'Manager' 'San Francisco']
 ['3' '1.0' 'Engineer' 'Boston']
 ['4' '1.0' 'Engineer' 'Boston']
 ['5' '2.0' 'Engineer' 'London']
 ['6' '2.0' 'Engineer' 'London']
 ['7' '2.0' 'Manager' 'New York']]
```

nothing changed and I don't understand why. the steps of algorithm I use are:

1. Create a cost matrix where the entries represent the cost of assigning an employee to a team. In this case, the cost could be defined as 1 if the employees are in different cities, and 0 if they are in the same city.
2. Run the Hungarian algorithm on the cost matrix to find a minimum-cost matching between employees and teams. The algorithm will find the minimum number of swaps needed to achieve a maximum number of employees in the same city.
3. Based on the minimum-cost matching, reassign employees to teams to maximize the number of employees in the same city.
4. The final output is a table with the reassigned employee ids, teams, positions, and cities

What am I doing wrong? How to fix my code?

Comment: Did you try to print the cost matrix and examine it, to figure out whether it represents the problem correctly or not?

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the condition: `employee_data[i, 2] == employee_data[j, 2] and employee_data[i, 3] != employee_data[j, 3]`

Comment: Also I would strongly advise you to encapsulate the code into functions, including the part of the code that builds the cost matrix. Ideally you want to test your code with different datasets, not just this one in particular. In particular you should test your code with very small datasets, with just 2 or 3 or 4 empoyees and 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 teams, and see where it breaks. So `employee_data` should rather be a function argument than a global variable.

Comment: @Stef The condition employee_data[i, 2] == employee_data[j, 2] and employee_data[i, 3] != employee_data[j, 3] checks if two employees have the same position (employee_data[i, 2] == employee_data[j, 2]) but work in different cities (employee_data[i, 3] != employee_data[j, 3]). In other words, it checks if two employees can be swapped without affecting the position but making sure that they are not working in the same city.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add these details in an easier form to read, comments are not optimal for long but clear explanations

Comment: @stef print of cost_matrix is:
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

Comment: Seriously, please [edit] your question to include this very relevant information. Don't post a whole matrix as a comment without linebreaks.

Comment: @Stef ok, im doing it. so do you have any ideas about correct solution?

Comment: Also, I note that (1) Your function `hungarian` actually does nothing except call `opt.linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)`, you could call `opt.linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)` directly without calling `hungarian` at all; (2) In function `redistribute_employees`, you write `row_ind, col_ind = hungarian(cost_matrix)` and then you use `col_ind` but you never use `row_ind`, I find that suspicious.

Comment: @Stef i don't use ```row_ind``` because i am using the final cost matrix cost to get the assignments. The cost matrix stores the final assignment costs and the indices of the assigned rows and columns can be obtained by finding the indices of the minimum values in each row and column of cost.

So, in this particular implementation, row_ind is not used, and the code relies on the cost matrix to obtain the final assignments.

Comment: @Stef seems like i did all steps correct but why i don't get right output?

Comment: How do you know that you did all steps correct?

Comment: Did you print `col_ind` and `row_ind` and checked that they corresponded to what you expected? Did you try your code with a smaller dataset like I suggested?

Comment: @Stef i am not sure. but i don't see where i made mistake

Comment: You are not sure whether you printed row_ind and col_ind and you are not sure whether you tried your code with a smaller dataset?

Comment: Debugging and making sure that code is correct does not happen by trying the code directly as a black box on a big example and hope it's correct, then be surprised when something is incorrect. You need to write tests for every small part of the code, and make sure that every small part of the code does what you believe it does. And print all the intermediary results to check them. Right now you're only looking at the final solution, and the final solution is wrong, and you have no idea why because you never looked at the intermediate results.

Comment: @Stef i am not sure that all steps are correct. i tested code with smaller data. still, the output is similar as input

Comment: @Stef yeah you are correct about debugging. i was testing all steps, but seems like i missed something. but at this point i'd like to get some help and maybe suggestions of correct code

Comment: I dont think the hungarian algorithm will work here,  it's to find minimum cost between different agents who can all preform every task.  and im guessin the reason u get the same table is that every swap is happening twice

Comment: to get the best solution, i think you need to go over all options, guessing a greedy solution of sorting the employees by cities and assigning the bigger cities to bigger groups will provide a close enough solution